Chargeback for car rental reimbursement
I rented a car in Germany. After one hour of driving the car signaled low engine oil. I stopped at a gas station and checked that the oil indeed was low. I called the rental company helpline and was instructed to buy and refill the oil, with a promise of reimbursement. I kept the bill and asked for the reimbursement after returning the car. Sadly, the company ignored my requests so far.
So, I attempted a chargeback on my revolut mastercard bank card, asking for the cost (50 EUR) back. I chose "my order doesn't match the description" as a reason from the drop-down menu. However, this was rejected by revolut with an explanation "Services that aren't as described must be cancelled for the customer to be eligible for a refund. We can only dispute the value of unused or unconsumed goods."
Am I out of luck or is there a way to persuade revolut to get involved? Perhaps there is a better way to phrase the request?
If the chargeback doesn't work, is there some small claims procedure in Germany that I could realistically use without appearing in court in person? Sending letters by post is fine. It is petty, but I feel like fighting for it as a matter of principle.

Your best approach is probably to make a public complaint on X or the company’s Facebook page, rather than any legal process. Companies hate having their dirty linen exposed on social media.

For the record Hertz had people arrested for "not returning cars" even though they did per the rental agreement.  About the best thing you could hope for is social media pressure or small claims court.

"the company ignored my requests so far" — how did you make these requests? You seem to have been able to reach someone before on the helpline. You weren't able to call it again to arrange the reimbursement? Do you have any record of the original conversation where they promised you a reimbursement? Even just a support case number?

@shim I made requests by email. Twice they replied they would look into it, other times they did not reply. It's been six weeks now. I can prove I called them using my billing records. I did not record the call, but at least they never denied making the promise. It did not occur to me to call them again, thanks for the suggestion.

Chargeback is not appropriate in this case since the charge was for rental, and rental is what you received. You have a contract dispute with the provider, and the proper avenue is through courts. Here's a small claims process for EU countries (except Denmark), and it looks like if you're lucky you may be able to do it all without physical appearances.
The thing is that even if you get a judgement in your favor, you'd still need to find a way to enforce it (i.e.: collect the money).
